# C++ class wrapped in SIP patched in Python

Tags: python, enums, wrapper

I'm creating a Python wrapper over some C++ library implementing some low-level M2M communication. I'm using Riverbank's SIP wrapper generator.

The C++ class has a method:

```
class Bar {
public:
    enum Status {
        ...
    };
    void setStatus(Status s);
    Status getStatus() const;
    ...
};
```

The class is contained in module `foo`.

SIP is using it's own enum type, but for few reasons I'd like to use Python 3.4 enum from standard libray.

I don't see any chance of accessing Python-defined classes from Python C API and I decided to patch wrapped class in `__init__.py`. The main reason is that I want to make dirty low-level work in C/C++/SIP and polish the class in Python (like add argument validation with sane error messages).

The Python `__init__.py` part looks like this (more or less):

```
from foo import Bar

class Status(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    ... and so on ...
Status.__module__ = 'Bar.Status'
Bar.Status = Status
Bar.status = property(...)
```

`Bar.status` will accept and return nice, pythonic `Bar.Status` enum.

Expected result is something like this:

```
class Bar(object):
    class Status(IntEnum):
         ...
    ...
```

I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with this approach, especially with patching the object at import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in other way that seems to be ok.

Let's consider a C++ library that contains two classes:

1. Foo
2. FooFactory

Wrapper library contains package `libfoo` (created in Python C API) and pythonic package `foo` (created in ordinary python). We don't access `libfoo` package directly, but import `foo`.

Package `foo`'s `__init__.py`:

```
from libfoo import Foo, FooFactory

# both are naked wrappers with ugly API derived from C++
# I defined some pythonic sugar that makes them nice to use

class FooPythonicGoodies(object):
    # add pythonic goodies here
    def quack(self):
        pass

# Merge them
Foo.__bases__ = Foo.__bases__ + (FooPythonicGoodies,)
```

Now, when anywhere in the sources I do this:

```
from foo import Foo, FooFactory

a = Foo()
a.quack()

# Factory is a C++ wrapped class that returns wrapped foo
# objects WITH FooPythonicGoodies!
factory = FooFactory()
b = factory.create_foo()
b.quack() # that works too!
```

That way I can polish rather un-pythonic C++ classes with a pythonic API sugar.